# accessing SBT settings under current scope

Tags: sbt

I'm having a problem trying to understand the concept of scope in sbt. I want a task to be run under a specific scope, and be able to access scoped settings, i.e.

**build.sbt**

```
name := "Superapp"

name in Test := "Testapp"

val printScopedKey = TaskKey[Unit]("psk", "Print Scoped Key")

printScopedKey := println("***** [APP NAME] " + name.value)
```

I'd expect the following:

```
> test:psk
> ***** [APP NAME] Testapp
```

Instead of the actual:

```
> ***** [APP NAME] Superapp
```

How can I do this in sbt? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 8):

OP wrote "I'd expect the following:"

```
> test:psk
> ***** [APP NAME] Testapp
```

Without actually defining `psk` task in `Test` configuration, sbt would look for `psk` task first in `Global` configuration, then in the order of `configurations` of the project, which by default is `Seq(Compile, Runtime, Test, Provided, Optional)`.

So the following (and @Jacek Laskowski's answer too) describes how one can go about in defining tasks into multiple scopes without code duplication. A setting can be scoped in three axes (project, configuration, and task). The project part doesn't come into play as much so we'll discuss configuration and task here.

It's recommended that task-specific settings are scoped to a task to encourage reuse of keys. For example:

```scala
test in assembly := {}
```

In the above `test` key is scoped to `assembly` task to control tests that are run before creating a fat JAR. You can define a "task-generator" method that would take a key and create a graph of settings around it:

```scala
def assemblyTask(key: TaskKey[File]): Initialize[Task[File]] = Def.task {
  val t = (test in key).value
  val s = (streams in key).value
  Assembly((outputPath in key).value, (assemblyOption in key).value,
    (packageOptions in key).value, (assembledMappings in key).value,
    s.cacheDirectory, s.log)
}
```

I use that to define `assembly`, `packageScala`, and `packageDependency` tasks.

```scala
lazy val baseAssemblySettings: Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
  assembly                   := Assembly.assemblyTask(assembly).value,
  packageScala               := Assembly.assemblyTask(packageScala).value,
  ....
)
```

So far `baseAssemblySettings` is configuration-neutral.

If I wanted to scope it in configurations like `Compile` and `Test`, I'd call `inConfig(conf)(settings)` like this:

```
lazy val assemblySettings: Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]] =
  inConfig(Compile)(baseAssemblySettings) ++
  inConfig(Test)(baseAssemblySettings)
```

Now you have multiple task graphs in multiple configurations.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the question! I'd initially thought I'd know the answer and then realized it's not so simple. I had to look around for a solution.

I use sbt **0.13.2-RC1**.

```
> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.2-RC1
[info] The current project is {file:/C:/dev/sandbox/0.13.2/}root-0-13-2 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.0-RC3
[info] Available Plugins: org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
```

I found the solution in [Mark Harrah's response to a similar question on the sbt mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/A87FFV4Sw4k/KPtygikQvogJ) that boils down to the following changes in **build.sbt**:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0-RC3"

name := "Superapp"

name in Test := "Testapp"

name in Runtime := "Runtimeapp"

lazy val psk = taskKey[Unit]("Print Scoped Key")

val pskSetting = psk := println("***** [APP NAME] " + name.value)

// https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/A87FFV4Sw4k/KPtygikQvogJ
val myPsks = Seq(Compile, Test, Runtime) flatMap { conf =>
  inConfig(conf)( Seq(pskSetting) )
}

myPsks
```

When the build file's loaded, sbt will *automagically* know that when you're executing `psk` its dependency is `name in Compile` while `test:psk` depends on `name in Test`. Pretty clever.

```
> psk
***** [APP NAME] Superapp
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 2014-03-26 21:27:37
> test:psk
***** [APP NAME] Testapp
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 2014-03-26 21:27:41
> runtime:psk
***** [APP NAME] Runtimeapp
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 2014-03-26 21:27:44
```

Use `inspect` to dig deeper. It's always quite useful to know how it works under the hood (which is not that hard to understand once you start using right tools, like `inspect`).